# Python Plotly-Dash remove "inline" from checklist so items are on separate lines

Tags: python-3.x, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I'm using Plotly's Dash library to create a checklist, and I want each item to be on its own line but I can't figure out how. Notice in the image below how "Delta P (PSI)" and "Horsepower" are on the same line, which I don't want.

Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

# Items to chart (checklist), based on unit type
html.Label('Items to Chart'), 

dcc.Checklist(

    options = [
        {'label': 'Delta P (PSI)', 'value': 'dtp'},
        {'label': 'Horsepower', 'value': 'hpe'},
        {'label': 'Hydraulic temp (C)', 'value': 'ht_egas'},
    ], 

    # What to use for className???
    className="checkbox or something..."
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
labelStyle = dict(display='block') # not 'inline'
```

https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/checklist

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

# Items to chart (checklist), based on unit type
html.Label('Items to Chart'), 

dcc.Checklist(

    options = [
        {'label': 'Delta P (PSI)', 'value': 'dtp'},
        {'label': 'Horsepower', 'value': 'hpe'},
        {'label': 'Hydraulic temp (C)', 'value': 'ht_egas'},
    ], 

    labelStyle = dict(display='block')
),
```

[image]